# $3^{4a+1} = 2b^2+1$ diophantine equation, $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I would like to solve the following diophantine equation : 
$$3^{4a+1} = 2b^2+1$$

Yet I don't know how to proceed.

What I found so far is just that $$(a, b) = (0,1)\ ,\  (1,11)$$ seem to be the only solutions...

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't think $(a,b)=(9,10)$ is a solution.

Comment: Since there is no further solution for $a\le 10^5$, it is very unlikely that further solutions exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was formulated by me on the forum in Russian [here-1](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/41254/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0) and [here-2](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/41388/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85) in connection with the generalization of the problem of identifying non-standard objects - counterfeit coins (see [here-3](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/dma.2015.25.issue-2/dma-2015-0007/dma-2015-0007.xml)). The upper bound of the length of such an algorithm corresponds to the Hamming boundary for ternary codes and has the form:

$1+ 2C_n^1+2^2C_n^2+…+2^t C_n^t=3^m,$

where $t$ is the maximum number of positions in which errors are corrected by the code.
For $t = 2$ this equality becomes

$1+2n^2=3^m.$

It is known that this equation has solutions: $(n, m) = (1,1), (2,2), (11,5)$, of which only one $n = 11, m = 5$ has a value in coding theory and problem [here-3]. In this case, for the parameters $n = 11, m = 5, t = 2$, a well-known perfect ternary Golay code (Wirtakallio-Golay code) and the perfect weighting algorithms, identifying up to 2 counterfeit coins ftom 11, are constructed.
On the forum, an outstanding mathematician (Russia, nickname falcao) wrote "For the case t = 2, the solution of the equation $1 + 2n ^ 2 = 3 ^ m$ was described by Nagel in 1923. True, I did not find the text of the article or proofs of the evidence on the Web."  Therefore, he gave his brilliant proof of the non-existence of other (different from the above) solutions of this equation.